# Azure VM command fails with no credential error

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli

I am running a command from the azure CLI to execute a script on a linux VM running in Azure.
The command looks like this:

```
az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunShellScript --name <\VMName> --resource-group <\RGName> --scripts "curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash"
```

The script installs azure CLI on the VM.

The command results into error:

`Could not retrieve credential from local cache for service principal 0cf4e5cf-de8f-4524-8be6-5e2exxxxxx. Please run 'az login' for this service principal.`

Can someone help me understand the problem here.
When I run the command without the piped sudo, the command works fine.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the same error as below***

```
az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunShellScript --name <\VMName> --resource-group <\RGName> --scripts "curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash"
```

[image]

This error may occur if you are not using latest version, please check your version like below and try to update your version:

```
az version
```

[image]

Also, I have tried logging in with my service principal in Azure CLI and tried running the command to install azure-cli inside the VM and it run successfully.

```
az login --service principal -u <AppID> -p <secret> --tenant <TenantID>
```

[image]

You can also ***install latest version*** locally by using this [MsDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli)

***Reference:***

[Azure CLI GitHub Action fails with Azure CLI 2.30.0: Could not retrieve credential from local cache for service principal · Issue #20154 · Azure/azure-cli · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20154)